# PayPal & oAuth tokens

Tags: paypal, oauth-2.0, paypal-subscriptions

I created a subscription (recurring payment) using REST API.

I end up having two tokens:

- Seller oAuth token (obtained through User id & secret)
- Member oAuth token (refresh and oAuth)

When I use the Seller Token I can trigger REST API's without problems.

If my understanding is correct, the agreement is between a Member and a Seller, hence both should be able read, suspend, reactivate and cancel the agreement.

QUESTION:

- What is the use of the Member's Refresh / OAuth ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're talking about the access token and the refresh token. Here are the main differences:

The access token is used when making API calls to show that you have permission to process a payment on behalf of a user. This is what you will always send through the authorization headers (typically something like "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_TOKEN"). Depending on the service you're using, these tokens do expire after a certain amount of time. Typically when you obtain an access token, you also get the refresh token and a value under expires_in. expires_in tells you how long you have until the token expires, and the refresh token is what you use to get a new access token once it expires.

The refresh token itself does not expire, and in the case of PayPal, the access token will expire after a period of 8 hours. Here's more information on the two: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/merchant-onboarding/obtaining-refresh-token-and-access-tokens/?mark=refresh%20token

Comment: Johathan - thanks for your answer and explanations.
Unfortunately, I am not referring to the refresh token.

Consider: 
when an agreement is created, the Member as well as the Seller have their own tokens, implying that both Seller and Member can perform operations on the agreement (i.e. cancel, suspend, etc.), as it should

I can use the Seller token to perform whatever REST operations I like.

So, the question is: WHY do I need the Member's oAuth2 token ?